# Can't clear floating divs

Tags: html, css

How to clear floating div's so that footer is pushed down? I have tried `:after` on a parent element, tried to insert clearing div, tried to add clear:both on the parent of the floating divs. None of it worked. What the issue here? So how to clear divs in this situation?

```css
* {margin: 0;}

html, body {height: 100%;}

.wrapper {
     min-height: 100%;
     height: auto !important;
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0 auto -4em;
     clear:both;
}
.left {
  width:50%;
  height:600px;
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;
}

p {font-size: 20px;}

.footer, .push {height: 140px; }

.footer {background-color: red;}
```

```html
   <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae voluptates fugiat ducimus nesciunt impedit vero iure rerum repellendus voluptatum, praesentium illum numquam a blanditiis quasi doloremque placeat animi consectetur quos.</p>
      </div>
    
    <div class="right">
      <p>right</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae voluptates fugiat ducimus nesciunt impedit vero iure rerum repellendus voluptatum, praesentium illum numquam a blanditiis quasi doloremque placeat animi consectetur quos.</p>
    </div>
     
        <div class="push"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jdstkv7o/ It's working for me :?

Comment: As a side note I also like to use `overflow:hidden;` on wrapper elements, I find it a less confusing way of clearing floats. Also, in your demo you need to make sure that push matches the margin bottom of the wrapper if you are doing a "Ryan Fait" sticky footer. So either `.wrapper{margin-bottom:-140px;}` OR `.footer, .push{ height:4em; }`

Answer (score 1):

Since `.footer` is the element you want to clear the floats, you put `clear: both` on the `.footer`.

Comment: It works, but clearing `.push` works as well. Can you explain why?

Comment: `.push` is also after the floated element, hence clears the float ... a `.push`'er were often used for older browser to clear float as the simpler `clear: both` didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {margin: 0;}

html, body {height: 100%;}

.wrapper {
     min-height: 100%;
     height: auto !important;
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
}
.left {
  width:50%;
  height:600px;
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;
}

p {font-size: 20px;}

.push{ clear: both; min-height: 1px; }

.footer{height: 140px; }

.footer {background-color: red;}
```

```html
   <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae voluptates fugiat ducimus nesciunt impedit vero iure rerum repellendus voluptatum, praesentium illum numquam a blanditiis quasi doloremque placeat animi consectetur quos.</p>
      </div>
    
    <div class="right">
      <p>right</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae voluptates fugiat ducimus nesciunt impedit vero iure rerum repellendus voluptatum, praesentium illum numquam a blanditiis quasi doloremque placeat animi consectetur quos.</p>
    </div>
     
        <div class="push"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {margin: 0;}

html, body {height: 100%;}

.wrapper {
     min-height: 100%;
     height: auto !important;
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0 auto -4em;
     clear:both;
}
.left {
  width:50%;
  height:600px;
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;
}
.push {clear:both;}
p {font-size: 20px;}

.footer {height: 140px; }

.footer {background-color: red;}
```

```html
   <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae voluptates fugiat ducimus nesciunt impedit vero iure rerum repellendus voluptatum, praesentium illum numquam a blanditiis quasi doloremque placeat animi consectetur quos.</p>
      </div>
    
    <div class="right">
      <p>right</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae voluptates fugiat ducimus nesciunt impedit vero iure rerum repellendus voluptatum, praesentium illum numquam a blanditiis quasi doloremque placeat animi consectetur quos.</p>
    </div>
     
    </div>
    <div class="push"></div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: your `<div class="push"></div>` has to be outside of the right div, because it's a floated one. After that you can apply a `clear:both` to put everything correct.